# Python i2c write_bus_data usage

Tags: python, i2c

8I have a number of 4 digit seven segment displays that I am trying to control using Beaglebone Black (running Ubuntu) and i2c.

The SSD's are Byvac BV4614's and the full datasheet [is available here](http://www.byvac.co.uk/downloads/datasheets/BV4614%20DataSheet.pdf).

I have wired up the circuit correctly using pins P9_19 and P9_20 on the Beaglebone. I have included pullup resistors and am using a [i2c logic converter](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/logic-level-i2c?keyword=i2c) for added safety.

I have verified the device using i2cdetect (it's 0x31 which is correct) and the device powers up nicely and enters it's i2c mode.

However I do not understand how to read or write data to the device using Python SMBbus. The SSD manual says

> The format used by this device consists of a command, this is a
>   number, followed by other bytes depending on that command. The method
>   of writing to the device using the I2C protocol follows a consistent
>   format, typically:  Where S-Addr is the
>   start condition followed by the device address (0x62). Command is one
>   of the commands given in the table. Data is one or more bytes and Stop
>   is the stop condition.

(on 7-bit addressing the device is at 0x31 which is what I'm using).

So if for example I wanted to get the SSD to display a number on digit 1 the manual says I have to do

> Command 5 - Name: Send number to digit -
>   Format:<S-addr><5><digit><byte><Stop>

My question is, how do I write that command using Python? I think i'm looking for something like this

```
import smbus
b = smbus.SMBus(1)
b.write_byte_data(0x31, 0x35, 0x30, 0x38)
```

which I'd like to mean "send command 5 (0x35) to device 0x31, digit 0 (0x30) and display the number 8 (0x38)" but wrrite_byte_data does not accept that number of arguments. I have also tried using write_i2c_block_data() which looks more hopeful but again I cannot work out how to use the functions correctly.

I feel that I am facing a BCK problem here but any help would be appreciated.

*edit*
Ok, I have tried

b.write_block_data(0x31, 5, [8, 0x38] )

which makes the number 8 appear on digit 3

b.write_block_data(0x31, 5, [2] )

makes 2 appear on digit 2. I've not yet worked out how to place anything on digit 1 or 4 yet.

b.write_block_data(0x31, 4, [44]) # just entering random stuff now

increases the brightness and then makes the SSD unresponsive.

So I'm getting closer,

*edit and SOLVED*

In the end it was ridiculously easy.

```
b.write_i2c_block_data(0x31, 5, [0, 8]) # write number 8 to digit 0
b.write_i2c_block_data(0x31, 5, [4, 5]) # write number 5 to digit 4 etc etc
```

According to http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-python/i2c-programming-in-python/using-the-i2c-interface-2 the function write_block_data is not very good.

> write_block_data(int addr,char cmd,long vals[])
>
> Write up to 32 bytes to a device.  This function adds an initial byte
>   indicating the length of the vals array before the valls array.  Use
>   write_i2c_block_data instead!

Comment: Just a comment: digit has to be is in the range 0-3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
b.write_i2c_block_data(0x31, 5, [0, 8]) # write number 8 to digit 0
b.write_i2c_block_data(0x31, 5, [4, 5]) # write number 5 to digit 4 etc etc
```

Solved the issue for me! All other commands in the spec now function as intended!

The page at http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-python/i2c-programming-in-python/using-the-i2c-interface-2 informed me that the function I was using was not ideal.